# How can I interface cAMP signal or membrane potential from slime mold to an electrode?

Tags: microbiology, electrophysiology

I am very much interested in measuring cAMP (cyclic adenosine mono phosphate) signal and membrane potential from amoeba. Since I want to try this as a hobby, what are the basic steps I must do to view these signals on a CRO (cathode ray oscilloscope). Cyclic-AMP being a biochemical, how can I view it as a corresponding electric signal?

Answer (score 1):

For cAMP there is only one electrophysiological technique I've found.  You can use cyclic nucleotide-gated channels in the cell as a secondary indicator of cAMP activity.  When cAMP increases in the cell, these channel will fast gate which you should be able to pick up.

The issue is standard CNGC's are not overly sensitive to cAMP and are typically more sensitive to cGMP.  But there have been mutants created that have a high affinity for cAMP.  You can transplant these in and have an easier time with the detection.

[This](http://physiologyonline.physiology.org/content/21/2/86) paper goes into a a lot more detail on it.

Comment: What do "fast gate" mean here ? Also how can I convert this biochemical signal to electrical so that I can see in a CRO?